# How to remove my corrupted mysql from wamp and connect separatly installed mysql to wamp?

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver

How to remove my corrupted mysql from wamp and connect separatly installed mysql to wamp?
If any body know please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just copy new mysql folder in wamp/bin/

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall wamp and reinstall override on the same wamp folder. I used to do that and got back all databases.